# What causes Arjuna 1603 (Could not find new XAResource to use for recovering non-serializable XAResource)

Tags: transactions, warnings, jboss6.x

I have no experience with Arjuna, but my log file gets filled with:

```
2011-06-27 09:25:18,021 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA-16037 Could not find new XAResource to use for recovering non-serializable XAResource  formatId=131076, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=28, tx_uid=0:ffff0a2012b7:126a:4e006635:2ba0, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a2012b7:126a:4e006635:2ba1, eis_name=unknown eis name

2011-06-27 09:25:18,021 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.jta] (Periodic Recovery) ARJUNA-16038 No XAResource to recover < formatId=131076, gtrid_length=29, bqual_length=28, tx_uid=0:ffff0a2012b7:126a:4e006635:2ba0, node_name=1, branch_uid=0:ffff0a2012b7:126a:4e006635:2ba1, eis_name=unknown eis name >
```

Those two messages always come together, and they are written periodically. The count of these messages increases with the uptime of the JBoss server instance. Since my application (it's an MDB consuming messages from a remote ActiveMQ) has some issues and these are the only log messages I get, I really want to know the reason for it.

Answer (score 37):

To get rid of the error, stop the jboss instance and remove the folder `$JBOSS/standalone/data/tx-object-store`

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what the files in this folder are and what they are needed for?

Comment: Or delete this directory when working in a domain:  $JBOSS/domain/servers/financials/data/tx-object-store

Answer (score 6):

Here are explanations:

- https://community.jboss.org/wiki/TxNonSerializableXAResource
- http://planet.jboss.org/post/norecoveryxa

Maybe your transaction lasts too long and you get into the timing issue described in the second link. Have you increased the server's transaction timeout ?

Comment: the links are all dead now. Maybe this could help: https://knowledge.broadcom.com/external/article/129101/arjuna016037-could-not-find-new-xaresour.html

Answer (score 4):

See [JBossDeveloper Forum#thread 221033](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/221033)

Essential part:

The simplest solution: 
Find this path 
{JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/data/tx-object-store/ShadowNoFileLockStore/defaultStore/StateManager/BasicAction/TwoPhaseCoordinator/AtomicAction

Inside AtomicAction find some transaction related files and after removing those files this issue will be solved.

But forum contains reasons and more 'system friendly' solution.